# How do you debug the close statement that is called by try-with-resources in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, try-with-resources

I am using Eclipse and I want to set the debugger to stop in the close statement that is automatically called by a try-with-resources.  I have trouble getting to the class, because it's one of those weird Spring proxy classes.  Is there some sort of trick to tell it just to stop in the close?

Comment: Can you please clarify more your situation with code parts ? Are you using resource management in try catch ?

Comment: What do you mean by, "have trouble getting to the class"?